# Ошибка 403 на CentOS

Tags: apache, httpd, centos

Такая проблема: есть сервер на CentOS 6.4. На нем сайт с конфигом:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.ru
        ServerAlias www.test.ru
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.ru/www
        <Directory /var/www/html/test.ru/www>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/html/test.ru/logs/error.log

        php_admin_flag register_globals 1
        php_admin_value date.timezone 'Europe/Moscow'
        php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/html/test.ru
        php_admin_value max_execution_time 360000
        php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/www/html/test.ru/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /var/www/html/test.ru/tmp
    </VirtualHost>
```

getenforce выводит Disabled. Тем не менее, все страницы возвращают 403 ошибку.
В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

403 - ошибка **приложения**, нет доступа к запрашиваемому действию. Просто у юзверя нет **прав**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте права доступа к директории сайта `/var/www/html/test.ru/www/`.
2. Убедитесь что выставленны 755 (`сhmod -R 755 /var/www/html/test.ru/www/`).
3. Попробуйте запросить любой статический файл (это поможет понять, относится ли проблема только к скриптам или к любым запросам).
4. Проверьте наличиие и если есть содержимое `.htaccess` файла в корне сайта.
5. Посмотрите логи сервера.